# How to get rid of the hero / tour infobox?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

Every few days when opening the hot questions site I get this infobox:
[image]

How to get rid of it for good? I tried closing with the <kbd>x</kbd> and taking the tour but that does not seem to help. After a few days the infobox is back.

PS: I am logged in as I can see my username in the header.

Comment: Do you delete your cookies often? Are you getting logged out?

Comment: No (never) and no.

Comment: A cookie is used to detect that you have closed the hero - it should not re-appear if cookies have not been cleared out.

Comment: I just looked at the cookies for stackexchange.com (browser is Chrome 36). `se-user` has a lifetime of one year, `hero` only until the end of the current browser session.

Comment: So it does. Looking.

Comment: So it was a bug after all. Delicious cookie bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cookie that indicates that the hero was closed was set to expire at the end of the session.

I have changed it to expire after a year, so this shouldn't be such a problem going forward.

Comment: Thanks. Will check it over the next days.

Comment: It works now for Stackexchange but I just realized, the same bug exists for all other SE pages for which I am not signed up (different hero box content but closed-cookie lifetime only session).

Comment: @BillyMailman - these were changes to se.com, not MSE... a completely separate codebase. Having said that, I've made the corresponding changes for the Q&A codebase ;)

Comment: Looks good, accepted.